# Getting a textbox value from a word document using ASP.NET?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, ms-word

I have a very basic web application written in ASP.NET(C#) and a basic Microsoft Word (2007) document that contains a text box and a dropdown list.

In my web application code behind file I would like to call the textbox control and a dropdown control by name and extract the values from them.

Any documentation that I have found online simply reads or writes a word document but I can't seem to find anything on accessing controls and extracting the values from them.

Any help would be greatly appreciated
Thank You

This is the only code that I have at the minute that does anything with the word document. It finds the word doc and opens it:

```
    //File path of the word document that contains the required values 
    string filePath = @"C:\Users\murphycm\Desktop\PlacesFile.docm";

    object fileToOpen = (object)filePath;

    //CREATING OBJECTS OF WORD AND DOCUMENT
    Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application oWord = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application();
    Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Document oWordDoc = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Document();

    oWordDoc = oWord.Documents.Open(ref fileToOpen);
```

Answer (score 2):

Unless you are going to install Microsoft Office on your server, I would recommend using the Open XML SDK 2.5 from Microsoft. With the SDK you can manipulate Microsoft Office documents for Office 2007 and higher:
http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=30425

Here's some code for getting text from a TextBox using both the OpenXML and Office Interop methods:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using DocumentFormat.OpenXml;
using DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Packaging;
using DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Wordprocessing;
using Word = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word;

namespace OpenXMLSDKTest
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            // Open XML Method
            object fileName = @"OpenXmlTest.docx";
            using (WordprocessingDocument myDocument = WordprocessingDocument.Open(fileName.ToString(), true))
            {
                var textbox = myDocument.MainDocumentPart.Document.Descendants<TextBoxContent>().First();
                Console.WriteLine(textbox.InnerText);
            }

            // Office Interop Method
            object missing = System.Reflection.Missing.Value;
            object readOnly = false;
            object isVisible = true;

            Word.Application wordApp = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application();
            wordApp.Documents.Open(ref fileName, ref missing, ref readOnly, ref missing, ref  missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref isVisible, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing);
            object firstShape = 1;
            string textFrameText = wordApp.ActiveDocument.Shapes.get_Item(ref firstShape).TextFrame.TextRange.Text;
            wordApp.Quit(ref missing, ref missing, ref missing);

            Console.WriteLine(textFrameText);

            Console.WriteLine("Press any key to continue...");
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: For this task I am required to use Microsoft Office, but thank you for the advice :)

Comment: Do you have Microsoft Office installed on your server?

Comment: Yes its installed, Office 2007

Comment: I've added code for both Office Interop and Open XML. This should get you started.

Comment: Neither of these worked for me with the XML I get the error "Sequence contains no elements" and using the Interop I get an out of bounds error on line "string textFrameText = wordApp.ActiveDocument.Shapes.get_Item(ref firstShape).TextFrame.TextRange.Text;"

Comment: Is there anyway to find the controls by their name, e.g. My textbox name is txtFrom and the dropdown name is ddPlacesFrom?

Comment: I figured you might be using the form elements and not the drawing elements. I don't know how to get these fields just yet, but I will continue researching.

Answer (score 0):

```
public List<string> GetTagsFromNewTemplate(string filePath)
        {
            var tags = new HashSet<string>();

            using (WordprocessingDocument myDocument = WordprocessingDocument.Open(filePath, false))
            {
                var textbox = myDocument.MainDocumentPart.Document.Descendants<DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Wordprocessing.Tag>().Select(x => x.Val);
                textbox.ForEach(x => tags.Add(x));
            }
            return tags.Distinct().ToList();
        }
```